# ROBLOX - If statement won't run inside of while loop?

Tags: lua, roblox

I've run into something really strange. I was originally trying to make a music script (more like system, tbh) and it had the same problem. Now I have boiled it down to a simple test:

```
while true do
    if script.Parent.musicstate.Value == true then
        print("Play")
    elseif script.Parent.musicstate.Value == false then
        print("Stop")
    end
    wait()
end
```

When I run it, it will either only print "Stop" or only print "Play." The string it will print will depend on the value of the bool value when the game *starts,* as in it does not change what it prints depending on the current value. All help will be appreciated, thanks!

The structure, SongScript is what is running:
[image]

Comment: 1. you don't need elseif, Since Value is bool.

Comment: 2. where do you update `script.Parent.musicstate.Value`? Is it updated in an Action call back?

Comment: I update the value directly from the side bar while testing (what's an action call back??)

Comment: Does it print either "Stop" or "Play" multiple times or just once?

Answer (score 0):

Never ever make such an infinite loop crashing your whole system! There is a lot more efficient way to do. You have the problem due to the fact that the script would auto break so it won't crash your whole system.

```
    script.Parent.musicstate.Changed:Connect(function()
    if script.Parent.musicstate.Value == true then
    print("Play")
elseif script.Parent.musicstate.Value == false then
    print("Stop")
    end
    end)
```

Comment: Yeah the script doesn't do anything anymore, not disabled and the structure has not changed :/ @Ahmad

Comment: I knew your problem. U are editing the value from ur client. Solo testing is filtering enabled. So change from Current Client to Current Server from test tab. and it will work. I hope this helped. @Frostbite

Comment: He has a wait() statement, it shouldnt crash the game.